# Barcode Doent Scan, Need a Barcode Font

Tags: fonts, crystal-reports, barcode-scanner

Could anyone help me out with barcode font. I have been using C128bHc and Free3of9 font to produce barcodes from numeric values to be used in Crystal Reports. But they dont scan. I dont know what variant I am using. I again produced a few from this website (http://www.terryburton.co.uk/barcodewriter/generator/) using Code128 to generate a barcode for '123456789' and client mentioned that it did work for them. I am confused. Could anyone help me find out an appropriate barcode font please? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same problem where I work. In my case there were two problems happening at the same time.

First, I discovered that you can't just type text and then use a barcode font. There is a conversion process that has to happen to format the data correctly with opening and closing tags. That's why entering data and using a barcode font isn't working but an image generated by a website does. The website is performing the conversion for you.

The software we use to format the data is found at IdAutomation.com.  There are other vendors out there, my company already had the software when I was hired. They are one of the big fish in the barcoding software market.

Second, the font we use is idautomationC128S. It prints a thinner barcode (height-wise) that doesn't eat up so much space on our reports. Specifically, we can use a larger font size without rows growing taller.

If you have these issues already worked out, I've included a sample formula below using an idautomation formula in Crystal reports that converts the data from a table to a usable format. You will also need to change the Font to a barcode format (but you probably already know that...)

```
IDAutomation_Code128 ({Table_SQL.field_name})
```

I hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

Find **IDAutomation.exe** for code 39 or for code 128 from internet [Its normally paid] and install it in your computer so it will be shown as a font in your computer. Now when you want to use it in crystal report change the font from the list as a IDAutomation128 font it will generate your ID into scanner readable barcode format[ FYI-*{XXXXXXX}*].